# Firefox reads .pdf files as text

Tags: firefox, pdf

When I run a .pdf file from a DVD with Firefox it reads it like the picture shows:

[picture here](http://s11.postimg.org/4bin1l92b/firefox_pdf.jpg)

[image: SU609536 example]

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2):

This is the binary content of your .pdf file which is simply shown as text. 
You can change the behaviour by changing the action for pdf files in **settings -> applications -> Portable Document Format (pdf)**. Just set the action to "**Preview in Firefox**" for the integrated pdf reader or "**download file**" or whatever you like to do with the pdf file.